# PHPExcel Sum with skipped columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

I just want to ask how can I sum columns horizontaly, skipping every 1 column? 
Here's the screenshot.

I just want to sum D9 and F9 only whic is the Branch Code. I want to disregard the column "r" which means rank. 
Please take note that the number of columns is dynamic, there are possibilities that
that there are 6 Branches with also 6 branch. Their values will be on the same row, how can I sort it out, by adding only those values under branches? Result should be under the net sales.

Thanks guys!

[image]

Comment: How would you do it in Excel itself? You could probably build a formula like `=SUM(D9,F9)` or `=D9+F9` by working out which columns you wanted to add, and building a string in PHP to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

If the "column heading" in row 8 is always an "r" for the columns you want skip, you can use an Excel formula of:

```
=SUMIF(C8:H8,"<>r",C9:H9)
```

to sum the values in range C9:H9 for each column where the value in range C8:H8 is not equal to the value "r"