# PHPExcel Sumif and Skip

Tags: php, phpexcel

I just want to ask if there's a function in `excel/phpexcel` that can SUM a range of 
cells but skip to add every one cell.

Ex. Range is `A1:G1` and it will only sum `A1+C1+E1+G1` skipping every 1 cell.

Or how can I do that? Please take note that range is dynamic. It could be `a1:g1` or further or less.

Answer (score 0):

Build the formula dynamically in your PHP script:

```
$startCell = 'A';
$endCell = 'H';
$row = 1;

$formula = '=' . $startCell . $row;
while ($startCell++ != $endCell && $startCell++ != $endCell) {
    $formula .= '+' . $startCell . $row;
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that I've also added a pure Excel formula answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318598/phpexcel-sum-with-skipped-columns)